# Is {∅} a subset of the power set of the power set of X, for every set X? {∅} ∈ ℘(℘(X))?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The concept of ∅ ∈ ℘(℘(X)) its clear to me, but ∅ is not the same as {∅}, so the statement that {∅} ∈ ℘(℘(X)) is not clear to me (please help).

Comment: $\varnothing\subseteq\wp(X)\implies\{\varnothing\}\in\wp(\wp(X))$. Note this says $\{\varnothing\}$ is an *element* of $\wp(\wp(X))$, not a *subset* of it. To see that $\{\varnothing\}$ is also a subset of it, observe $\varnothing\in\wp(\wp(X))\implies\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\wp(\wp(X))$.

Answer (score 3):

The following all mean the exact same thing:

1. $\{\emptyset\}\in \mathscr P(\mathscr P(X))$
2. $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq \mathscr P(X)$
3. Every element of $\{\emptyset\}$ is an element of $\mathscr P(X)$
4. $\emptyset \in \mathscr P(X)$
5. $\emptyset\subseteq X$

1 and 2 are equivalent by the definition of $\mathscr P$

2 and 3 are equivalent by the definition of $\subseteq$

3 and 4 are equivalent since the only element of $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\emptyset$

4 and 5 are equivalent by the definition of $\mathscr P$

And of course 5 is true, regardless of what $X$ is ("every element of the empty set is an element of $X"$ is vacuously true).

Answer (score 0):

∅ is a subset of any set, so ∅ ⊆ X.

Then, ∅∈℘(X). Then, {∅} ⊆ ℘(X). Therefore, {∅} ∈ ℘(℘(X)).